# Is Munkres referring to the topology generated by the basis here?

Tags: general-topology

In the following lemma, is $\mathcal{T}$ necessarily the topology generated by the basis $\mathcal{B}$? I ask because it's not immediately clear to me, and also I don't see why the first sentence would be true unless $\mathcal{T}$ was the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$.

[image]

Comment: "Let $\mathscr B$ be a basis for a topology $\mathscr T$ on $X$." This is equivalent to saying "Let $\mathscr T$ be a topology on $X$, and let $\mathscr B$ be a basis for $\mathscr T$.", or $Let $\mathscr T$ be the topology on $X$ generated by the basis $\mathscr B$."

Comment: Yes. The lemma states "let $\mathscr{B}$ be a basis for [a topology] $\mathscr{T}$". That means $\mathscr{T}$ is the topology generated by $\mathscr{B}$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $\mathcal{T}$, or equivalently, $\mathcal{T}$ is the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$. If you reread the section where Munkres introduces bases for topologies, you can remind yourself of the various equivalences and definitions around bases, topologies, and a basis for a topology.